# Symfony ClassLoader won't load

Tags: php, symfony, psr-0, spl-autoloader

I'm developing a small php framework for personal use. I am trying to autoload classes with UniversalClassLoader which is used in Symfony, but when I try to use some these classes I got error

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/web/globeapi/Start.php on line 14

Here is `Start.php` file code.

```
    require('../libraries/loader/Loader.php');

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$auto   = require('../config/Auto.php');


$Loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$Loader->registerNamespaces($auto);
$Loader->register();


Controller::test();
```

Here is code of Controller class

```
    namespace Libraries\Controller;

class Controller
{
    function Controller()
    {
        
    }
    
    public static function test()
    {
        echo 1;
    }
}
```

here is code of Auto.php file which returns array of classes for autoloading.

```
 return array(
        'Libraries\Controller'      => '../libraries/controller/Controller.php',
        'Libraries\Module'          => '../libraries/module/Module.php',
        'Libraries\View'            => '../libraries/view/View.php',
        'Libraries\Sammy'           => '../libraries/sammy/Sammy.php',
        'Libraries\Routes'          => '../config/Routes.php'
);
```

Comment: Does  \Libraries\Controller::test(); work?

Comment: Hint: using the universal class loader it is not necessary to have an array containing all the classes and files. Have a look to http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html

Comment: well neither \Libraries\Controller::test(); doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is using the current version of Symfony (2.2) and the UniversalClassLoader. The general idea is to follow the PSR-0 standard so that you don't have to define a mapping entry for each file. Just by following simple naming and location conventions your classes will be found - neat, isn't it? :-) (note that both directory and file names are case sensitive).

The **directory structure** (the vendor directory is created by composer)

```
app.php
composer.json
src
  App
    Libraries
      Controller
        Controller.php
vendor
  symfony
     class-loader
       Symfony
         Component
           ClassLoader
```

The **composer.json**

```
{
  "require": {
      "symfony/class-loader": "2.2.*"
  }
}
```

The content of **app.php**:

```
require_once 'vendor/symfony/class-loader/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespace('App', 'src');
$loader->register();

\App\Libraries\Controller\Controller::test();
```

And finally the **controller class**:

```
//src/App/Libraries/Controller/Controller.php
namespace App\Libraries\Controller;

class Controller
{

    public static function test()
    {
        echo 1;
    }
}
```