# UniversalClassLoader is not loading classes

Tags: php, symfony, psr-0, spl-autoloader

I writing a smal php mvc framework, and i want to autoload my clases like Controller, Model etc.For that purpose iam try to use UniversalClassLoader from Symfony and he just wont load classes, and when i try to use them i get this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'APP\Libraries\Controller\Controller' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/web/globeapi/Bootstrap.php on line 24
```

here is Bootstrap.php

```
require('../libraries/loader/UniversalClassLoader.php');
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

class Bootstrap
{
    function Bootstrap()
    {

    }

    public static function run()
    {
        $auto = require('../config/Auto.php');



            $SPL = new UniversalClassLoader();
            $SPL->registerNamespace('APP\Libraries\Controller', '../libraries/controller/Controller.php');
            $SPL->register();



        APP\Libraries\Controller\Controller::test();

    }
}
```

here is Controller.php

```
namespace APP\Libraries\Controller;

class Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo 1;
    }

    public static function test()
    {
        echo 1;
    }
}
```

I have also tryed MapClassLoader but the result is same.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505455/symfony-classloader-wont-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need to register the main namespace. The second parameter needs to be a path and not a file. Also try with absolute not relative path. The next problem is that your directories are lower case. So the autoloader is expecting the path `LIB_FOLDER/APP/Libraries/Controller` for a namespace `APP\Libraries\Controller`. I don't know if you can set aliases for converting lowercase to uppercase. But it dosn't seem so.

Try something like that:

```
$SPL->registerNamespace('APP', __DIR__.'/../LIB_FOLDER');
```